# Scraping table with beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to retrieve `tr` from the nested table `#timeTable` from [this webpage](https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?func=TT&ReservationType=npgres.exe%3FPM%3DBO&Leg1i=PRJ&Leg1ii=BEV&Leg1Date=26%2F02%2F2019&TotalPassengers=1&TotalPassengersHuman=1&TotalPassengersAcce=0&TotalVehicles=0).

I've tried the following but it gives an empty array.

```
nlg_timetable_url = "https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?func=TT&ReservationType=npgres.exe%3FPM%3DBO&Leg1i=PRJ&Leg1ii=BEV&Leg1Date=26%2F02%2F2019&TotalPassengers=1&TotalPassengersHuman=1&TotalPassengersAcce=0&TotalVehicles=0"
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
request = urllib.request.Request(nlg_timetable_url,headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
ngl_timetable_table = list(soup.select('#timeTable tr'))
print(ngl_timetable_table)
```

Output

```
[]
```

Comment: Working for me.  Did you have a proper response/soup object?

Comment: please include the rest of your code

Comment: I get a proper soup object but when I print ngl_timetable I get empty an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use requests module

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
nlg_timetable_url = "https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?func=TT&ReservationType=npgres.exe%3FPM%3DBO&Leg1i=PRJ&Leg1ii=BEV&Leg1Date=26%2F02%2F2019&TotalPassengers=1&TotalPassengersHuman=1&TotalPassengersAcce=0&TotalVehicles=0"
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
res = requests.get(nlg_timetable_url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('#timeTable tr'):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way it can work with urrlib as I would like to use the urllib.parse.urlencode() to pass parameters to compose the URL.

Comment: you can still do that first before passing that to requests.